# WooCommerce Add to cart button error: "choose product options"

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce

In WooCommerce variable.php I have this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Variable product add to cart
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.1.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $product, $post;
?>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>

<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data' data-product_id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" data-product_variations="<?php echo esc_attr( json_encode( $available_variations ) ) ?>">
    <?php if ( ! empty( $available_variations ) ) : ?>
        <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
            <tbody>
                <?php $loop = 0; foreach ( $attributes as $name => $options ) : $loop++; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="label"><label for="<?php echo sanitize_title($name); ?>"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $name ); ?></label></td>
                        <td class="value"><select id="<?php echo esc_attr( sanitize_title( $name ) ); ?>" name="attribute_<?php echo sanitize_title( $name ); ?>">
                            <option value=""><?php echo __( 'Choose an option', 'woocommerce' ) ?>&hellip;</option>
                            <?php
                                if ( is_array( $options ) ) {

                                    if ( isset( $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                        $selected_value = $_REQUEST[ 'attribute_' . sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                    } elseif ( isset( $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ] ) ) {
                                        $selected_value = $selected_attributes[ sanitize_title( $name ) ];
                                    } else {
                                        $selected_value = '';
                                    }

                                    // Get terms if this is a taxonomy - ordered
                                    if ( taxonomy_exists( sanitize_title( $name ) ) ) {

                                        $orderby = wc_attribute_orderby( sanitize_title( $name ) );

                                        switch ( $orderby ) {
                                            case 'name' :
                                                $args = array( 'orderby' => 'name', 'hide_empty' => false, 'menu_order' => false );
                                            break;
                                            case 'id' :
                                                $args = array( 'orderby' => 'id', 'order' => 'ASC', 'menu_order' => false, 'hide_empty' => false );
                                            break;
                                            case 'menu_order' :
                                                $args = array( 'menu_order' => 'ASC', 'hide_empty' => false );
                                            break;
                                        }

                                        $terms = get_terms( sanitize_title( $name ), $args );

                                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                            if ( ! in_array( $term->slug, $options ) )
                                                continue;

                                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $term->slug ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $term->slug ), false ) . '>' . apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $term->name ) . '</option>';
                                        }
                                    } else {

                                        foreach ( $options as $option ) {
                                            echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( sanitize_title( $option ) ) . '" ' . selected( sanitize_title( $selected_value ), sanitize_title( $option ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variation_option_name', $option ) ) . '</option>';
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select> <?php
                            if ( sizeof( $attributes ) == $loop )
                                echo '<a class="reset_variations" href="#reset">' . __( 'Clear selection', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>';
                        ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

        <div class="single_variation_wrap" style="">
            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_variation' ); ?>

            <div class="single_variation"></div>

            <div class="variations_button">
                <?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?>
                <button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt"><?php echo $product->single_add_to_cart_text(); ?></button>
            </div>

            <input name="add-to-cart" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $post->ID ); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" />

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_variation' ); ?>
        </div>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button' ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="stock out-of-stock"><?php _e( 'This product is currently out of stock and unavailable.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form' ); ?>
```

But when I choose the size and then click Add to cart, I get an error with which says "choose product options".
Does somebody know how to fix this? It's like the form and the button aren't working "together".

Comment: I suggest starting over with WooCommerce's `variable.php` template. And/or disabling your plugins and custom scripts. You have some kind of error. Do you see anything in your browsers developer console?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.
The thing you had to fill in, was for the `<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="" />`
So i gave it as value the product id and it worked :D
So like this:

```
        <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" value="<?php echo $product->id; ?>" />
```

Comment: This input is supposed to be dynamically modified by WooCommerce's script when the actual variation is chosen. You have incorrectly modified it to be the ID of the variable product.